# is there a way to simplify this terminal class I wrote or make it more efficient :) thnks

Tags: java, terminal

To run the terminal from my intelliJ I wrote next code:

```
public static String runTerminalCommand (String command){

        Process proc = null;
        try {
            proc = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(command);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        // Read the output

        BufferedReader reader =
                new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(proc.getInputStream()));

        String line = "";
        try {
            while((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                out.print(line + "\n");
                return line;
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        try {
            proc.waitFor();
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;

    }
```

If there is a way to simplify this :)

Comment: You should ask this in [code review](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: One thing - you're not closing your reader, which could lead to a memory leak (the underlying resource wouldn't be closed even if the object is garbage collected).  For Java7 and above, look up try-with-resources : https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/tryResourceClose.html

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it belongs on CodeReview.SE

Answer (score 1):

I would first look into **correctness** here; that one line:

```
           return line;
```

looks suspicious. Or, more precisely: are you **sure** that your command will always print exactly **one** line? Because you are returning after reading the first line; and thus omitting any other output.

Besides: you should change your code to use try-with resources instead - your return statement just leaves your readers unclosed. Probably not a problem here because all of that should go away when the process object goes away, but still: bad practice. "Cleanup things" before exiting your methods!

To answer the actual question: after looking into these conceptual things I am pointing out, there isn't much else you could do. Probably use a ProcessBuilder instead of the somehow "outdated" Runtime.exec() call.